# AMPPS Export WordPress To A Server

Tags: wordpress, ampps

I'm using AMPPS to Build A WordPress site that I will export to my hosting after it is built. I'm using the AMPPS default username and password for the database. Will I be able to change these to something more secure once I have exported the site to my hosting. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can update these details to something more secure when you clone a new site.